# Filling data frame with values from different row after group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame which looks like that:

| id | D1 | D2 | D3 | max_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 30,55 |
| 001 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 38,98 |
| 002 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 24,59 |
| 002 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 33,24 |

```
df <- read.table(text="
id  mast merti cysts max_date
001     1   0   0   30,55
001     0   0   0   38,98
002     0   1   0   24,59
002     1   0   0   33,24", header = TRUE)
```

I need to edit this to look like this

| id | D1 | D2 | D3 | d1_date | d2_date | d3_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 30,55 | 38,98 | 38,98 |
| 002 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 33,24 | 24,59 | 33,24 |

I tried something like this

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% separate(illness, into=c("D1","D2", "D3"), 
                       sep=",") %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(
                         d1_date = ifelse(D1 == 1, max_date, NA),
                         d2_date = ifelse(D2 == 1, max_date, NA),
                         d3_date = ifelse(D3 == 1, max_date, NA))
```

The results I obtain

| id | D1 | D2 | D3 | d1_date | d2_date | d3_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 30,55 | NA | NA |
| 001 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NA | NA | NA |
| 002 | 0 | 1 | 0 | NA | 24,59 | NA |
| 002 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 33,2 | NA | NA |

And i can't find the way to properly add this d1_date ... d3_date.

Comment: hi jakim! can you explain the logic a bit for me. Why is d3_date 38,98, and 33,24?

Comment: @Mark it's the date of examinations. I have all examnation dates, regarding of outcome (1 or 0). For example in 1st row of what should be: d1 was diagnosed od d1_date, d2 and d3 weren't diagnosed at all so in this case i fill d2_date and d3_date with the date of the last exam, so they can be the same. And this date of diagnosis (regarding if positive diagnose or the lat one) is in max_date in the original df.

Comment: I don't know if I follow, but basically, I understood it to mean that if a value is 1, then take the value in that row, otherwise, take the last value for the ID?

Comment: did you try my code? :-)

Comment: @Mark, you're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
answer <- df |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, max_date), names_to = "disease") |>
  summarise(date = ifelse(all(!value), last(max_date), max_date[which(value == 1)]), .by = c("id", "disease"))
```

To turn it back into a wide format, like the desired output, you can use something like:

```
answer2 <- pivot_wider(answer, names_from = "disease", values_from = "date", names_glue = "{disease}_date")
# or 
answer3 <- answer2 |> left_join(df |> summarise(across(-max_date, sum), .by = id), by = "id")
```

Comment: In the real data I have three diseases names instead of D (These are medical data, and I can't put here the real ones), so no it don't working, and I'm thinking what should I change to make this work.

Comment: @jakim_M what are the column names of the real dataset?

Comment: And I cant have this in a tidy way (I would prefer data this way, but I can't) because then the data will go to another program and I need separate columns for each disease and date.

Comment: mast, merti, cysts

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this works for you:

```r
library(dplyr) # dplyr_1.1.0 or newer for `.by=`
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, max_date)) %>%
  filter(value == 1 | all(value == 0), .by = c(id, name)) %>%
  mutate(max_date = if_else(value == 1, max_date, max(max_date)), .by = id) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1, by = c(id, name))  %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = "name", values_from = c("value", "max_date"))
# # A tibble: 2 × 7
#      id value_mast value_merti value_cysts max_date_mast max_date_merti max_date_cysts
#   <int>      <int>       <int>       <int> <chr>         <chr>          <chr>         
# 1     1          1           0           0 30,55         38,98          38,98         
# 2     2          1           1           0 33,24         24,59          33,24
```

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), mast = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), merti = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), cysts = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), max_date = c("30,55", "38,98", "24,59", "33,24")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I tried your soultion on real data, aan I received this error message: Error in `arrange()`:
ℹ In argument: `..1 = -value`.
Caused by error in `-value`:
! invalid argument to unary operator. The max date is numeric and id is character.

Comment: Actually, it's not required, was in an early code path that I never optimized out.

Comment: However, if by chance there are still problems, please post the output from `dput(head(df, 4))` (or some number that presents at least two complete `id`s) in addition to the nice table? There is ambiguity in the markdown/html table, and the output from `dput` will fix that.

Comment: @r2evans OP added the actual column names in a comment on my answer. I added them as column names in a read.table in the question if you want! :-)

Comment: Sure, but ... in addition to the error mentioned, I think it's _far better_ if the user posted unambiguous representative data, I don't want to chase what I don't know

Comment: @r2evans I've heard it said that data science is 90% data wrangling. I'd add to that by saying answering StackOverflow questions is 90% question asker wrangling :P

Comment: That's an interesting way to frame it, I agree... I typically think of it as "teaching how to ask questions well for fast and actionable answers". I've found (at least for me) asking questions _well_ is a skill that often needs to be learned, as well as refined/improved. I've started asking many questions on SO where my inner voice (including the pre-fab comments I paste into many questions) directs me to include things that eventually help me to find the resolution without pressing `Post question`.

Comment: @jakim_M, I edited my answer to work with your updated data.